# How to change Content-Type of GET-Request via firefox addon RESTClient

Tags: rest, jersey, content-type, rest-client, media-type

I want to send GET-Requests which shall be answered by my REST-API.
My java programm currently supports `text/plain`, `text/html`, `text/xml` and `application/json` using the JAX-RS Reference Implementation Jersey.

To test the different media types I'm using the firefox addon `RESTClient`. To change the media type I shall adjust the header with `name=Content-Type` and e.g. `value=text/xml`.

[image]

But the RESTClient always returns `text/html` no matter which `Content-Type` I choose. The only way right now to modify the returned result type is, to uncomment the html-section in my code. Then `text/plain` will be the returned media type, but still the `Content-Type` argument of the RESTClient stays ignored.

I'm using the most resent version of RESTClient, which is right now 2.0.3. Can you please help me?

Here is my Java-Code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class restProvider {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello little World";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello little World" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  // Uncommenting the following 6 lines will result in returning text/plain
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello World" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello little World" + "</h1></body>" + "</html> ";
  }

  // This method is called if JSON is requested
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String getJson(){
      Gson gsonObject = new Gson();
      return gsonObject.toJson(helloClass);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have to specify the `Accept` header with the media type you want in addition to the Content-Type header that states what is the content type of your request, NOT the content type of the response which indeed is set by the `Accept` header

So use the **Accept** header instead of Content-Type header

Comment: Thanks! I added the header `Accept: text/xml` and I got the requested response format.

Comment: Hello how to add Accept: text/xml in any GET HTTP urls